# templateUrl issue related to ag-grid v19

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

ag-grid is not rendering the column with templateUrl option.

Is there something that is missing?

Here is the plnkr with required code for templateUrl:
Click here to see the code " https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Qvkh66hfzmyDltzA?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview "

The "test" column is configured with templateUrl, which has to be rendered from the given HTML file. Instead, the column is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [plunk I've updated](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/2P8RQJvWy0NFne7y?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

When you mention `templateUrl:'./test.html'` for `ColDef`, the same file has to be there inside the same folder under which the script file is there.
I've just placed the same file under `lib` folder and you can see the template rendered for `test` column.

Comment: After putting the test.html file inside of script folder then also the template is not rendered for test column.  You can see code here  " https://next.plnkr.co/edit/8dhCDfrQBOTIrgxv?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview "

Comment: I guess it takes some time to load and render... working for me. Observe after 5-10 seconds.

Comment: But i am not getting any type of text after 10 minute also and when i resize the size of plunker  i am getting a full html text without parsing, that is not acceptable.

Comment: you can log a ticket to [tag:ag-grid] team for that